# Is there a CFD program that can simulate the motion of a non rigid body through fluid?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, cfd

Is there a CFD program that can simulate motion of a conveyor belt underwater? Aproximating it as a moving rigid plate is not gonna work.

Comment: Yes, several. What is your budget?

Comment: Not more than 500 USD. We get access to autodesk programs and ansys student versions at university. Could it be done in one of these?

Comment: Not sure you can get decent cfd packages even with their student pricing hhat cheap. You want a Rolls Royce on the budget for a skateboard.

Comment: You could put in the effort to code up your own model.  Shouldn't be too bad after you learn to code.  Results might be better than some random mesher.

Comment: I know someone who has written code to do this. contact me through my website, www,nielsenkillowatt.com and I will introduce you.

Comment: Check out: cham.co.uk